# Search Play Store history for an app?

Tags: google-play-store

My droid phone died recently and I got a replacement. I was trying to install a phone silencer app that I liked which was on my old phone, but I couldn't find the exact one in the Play Store. Is there a way I can search my old Play Store history? Or is that information lost with the old phone?

Comment: go to my apps in google play browse all the apps

Comment: @user3275057 that's exactly it. Can you make that an answer on this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to my apps in google play browse all the apps

Note: Made as answer as requested